# how to send image from one activity to another, fetching records in listview using xml parser

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

problem in image sending, able to send text to another activity, placing some source code with file name please see and tell me the mistake and possible so please writedown the required code because i am facing this problem for last two days:-

```
MainActivity Code:-
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
         // getting values from selected ListItem
            String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById
            (R.id.title)).getText().toString();
            String artist = ((TextView) view.findViewById
            (R.id.artist)).getText().toString();
            String duration = ((TextView) view.findViewById
            (R.id.duration)).getText().toString();
            byte[] array = null;
            Bitmap thumb_url = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray
            (array, 0, array.length);


        //  Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray
            (array, 0, array.length);

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
            in.putExtra(KEY_ARTIST, artist);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DURATION, duration);
            in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, thumb_url);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });     
}   
}

SingleMenuItemActivity 
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// XML node keys
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
private static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
private static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    String artist = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);
    String duration = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DURATION);
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("thumb_url");
    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);

   //what code to write for image here 

    lblName.setText(title);
    lblCost.setText(artist);
    lblDesc.setText(duration);

listitem.xml:-
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView     
        android:id="@+id/thumb_url"   
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/rihanna"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip">
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Duration: " >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#acacac" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left">
    </TextView>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is click method

```
in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, thumb_url);
```

and receive image useing `setBackgroundResource`.

```
 ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 bitmap.setBackgroundResource(thumb_url);
```